# Creating cron jobs

Tags: php

I'm trying to schedule a process, I have it saved on a table that includes the desired datetime to run.

I just don't know how to approach this, should I create an entry for each user-created process, or should I just create one single entry, that runs a script every X minutes that checks the DB for processes that are supposed to be run, and runs them?

**Edit:**
I am looking for pros/cons of each approach and guidance from anyone who has dealt with task scheduling. I also would like to keep it platform independent, but that's not a requirement.
I'm currently working on a linux machine.

Comment: Do you own a linux server with cPanel ?

Comment: I'd prefer a platform agnostic solution.

Comment: platform as no cpanel, or platform as in window/mac/linux?

Comment: windows/mac/linux. Also I intend to automate any task scheduling as I don't want users to have to "get their hands dirty". The idea is: run an install, and never worry about it again.

Comment: @localhost Which platform are you currently developing on? Windows, Linux or mac? Each of them have a different basis of "Cron" or "Scheduled Tasks" so please define what one you are currently developing or wanting advice on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to define the need (or not) of a few properties first:

- Resilience against script failure
- Locking (single instance script) if needed
- Ease of management
- Possibility to follow dependencies (A must be run before B)
- Ability to come up on boot without manual intervention
- No starvation of interactive performance by background processes

Considering these, I typically use the following scheme:

- Create a single OS-level scheduler tick, that runs a worker script every n seconds (Cron, Windows scheduler, whatever). This will be your only platform-specific part
- If OS-level scheduler is too coarse, schedule a wrapper script, that starts the worker script a few times scheduled by `usleep()`, until OS-level granularity is reached
- Inside the worker script first of all do bookkeeping: Write a flagfile or, if it exists, check it for a stalled-worker-deadlock, possibly alerting on error
- After that, start a cycle:
- - dequeue one work item (dependency and sequence go here), marking it as started
- - run this work item, marking it as complete
- - update your flagfile to show your progress
- when finsihed, kill your flagfile and end

I have had good results with this approach for quite some poll-only workloads.

**Edit**

Forgot one: If you want parallelism, simply start parallaelable work items concurrently

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an entry for each user-created process, so they "heavy" job is done by cron, which has been made for that. Besides, the other approach would need you to run the script that checks the DB for a period small enough so any user-created process would run as scheduled.

Comment: Well, I imagine a 10 minute interval should sufice. One thing I just realized is that adding each process to the cron won't be very easy to achieve on a multiplatform approach.

Comment: @user2553780 Not sure if it is a problem in your system, but if you have many users and many processes to run, you may introduce unwanted extra load to your server every 10 minutes. But depends on your target application anyway.